# How to limit console view to only the user who triggered the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) plugin with Jenkins. In my setup, users have only access to their own "trigger job" that trigger a shared job with different parameters. As I do not want a user to see the console log of runs triggered by other users in that shared job, access to the shared job is restricted. But ideally, I'd like to give a user access to the console log of those runs of the shared job that the user itself triggered (via the trigger job).

Is there a way to achieve this, e.g. via [macro extensions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin/blob/master/docs/MACROS.md) and / or the [Ownership Plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ownership/)?